# How can I assign a listener to all elements witihin a javascript array of elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, addeventlistener

Basically, what I want to know is what can I do that would essentially work like this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('particle')[all].addEventListener('mouseover', Jump, false);
```

I have already tried using a for loop and it froze the browser:

```
for(var i=0; i <= document.getElementsByClassName('particle').length, i+1){
  document.getElementsByClassName('particle')[i].addEventListener('mouseover', Jump, false);
}
```

Why didn't that work?
What can I do to achieve this effect?

Also I tried:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('particle')[0,1,2,3,4].addEventListener('mouseover', Jump, false);
```

However, that also didn't work. . . It only worked on the first and last elements but not on any others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `for` loop is the right approach.

```
for(var i=0; i <= document.getElementsByClassName('particle').length, i+1){
```

should be

```
for (var i=0; i<document.getElementsByClassName('particle').length; i+=1) {
```

Also, it would be more efficient if you only query the DOM once:

```
var particles = document.getElementsByClassName('particle');
for (var i=0; i<particles.length; i+=1) {
    particles[i].addEventListener('mouseover', Jump, false);
}
```

Comment: Yeah I had tried the single DOM query thing also, but I didn't realize I needed to use i+=1 instead of i+1, thanks.

Comment: This still checks particles' length on every iteration (which could change over the course of the loop) -- you should cache this as well to be super-speedy.
var i, len, particles=document.getElementsByClassName('particle');
for (i=0, len=particles.length; i<len; i++) { ... }

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

```
for(var i=0; i <= document.getElementsByClassName('particle').length, i+1){
```

should be

```
for(var i=0; i < document.getElementsByClassName('particle').length; i++){
                ^                                                  ^   ^
```

First error: Since i starts with 0, you should use `<` instead of `<=`
Seconde error: `,` should be `;`
Third error: `i` should be reassigned value in the loop, so it should be `i++` instead of `i+1`

And please note that getElementsByClassName() is not [available up to and including IE8](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#gettingelements).

Make sure your browser supports this method.